# Cannot upgrade libc6, "Already newest version"

Tags: linux, virtualbox, apt-get, libc, linux-mint

I have recently installed Linux Mint on a new machine and I am trying to download virtual box.

The problem is it won't download because of this error:

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libc6 (>=2.27)
```

When I run:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

It tells me

```
libc6 is already the newest version (2.23-0ubuntu10).
```

When I update the cache of my software sources I get the message that it could not download all repository indexes so I assume it might be related to that but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: This is a system administration question, not a programming question. Go to the relevant sister site. BTW you should avoid mixing distribution packages with external sources.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens when you try to run the wrong version (build) of the application in your system.

[image: img_VirtualBox_Error]

As an example, the current Virtualbox version is 6.1.22. And I download it for the  `Ubuntu 19.10 / 20.04 / 20.10 / 21.04` host because there is no separate download link available for Linux Mint distribution. **But my Linux Mint distribution is 19.3 cinnamon** and **Mint 19.3 is based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**. So, the **Virtualbox version which is built for Ubuntu 20.04, 20.10, 21.04 is not going to work for the distribution which is using Ubuntu 18.04**. This is the reason for getting ( `Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libc6 (>=2.29)` ) error.

When I downloaded the Virtualbox which is particularly built for `Ubuntu 18.04` everything worked fine :)

For more clarity watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1K2zx32tBwA

OR, just download the VirtualBox from the **Software Center**. that will work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the issue but I managed to download virtual box through the software manager.

Comment: Software center/manager is OK but it contains old packages  as compared to the latest release